# Issue converting .ply to LAS then LAS to COPC , losing colour information

Tags: las, pdal, ply, copc

Using PDAL to convert .ply file with colour information to LAS, I can verify I see the colour information in cloud compare.
However, when converting the LAS to COPC , I'm losing the colour information in the COPC viewer.

If I convert the .ply to LAS using cloud compare, then using PDAL to convert LAS to COPC, colour information is there.

Using PDAL translate with a_srs set using the EPSG code for the data, again with the LAS and COPC output.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so found the issue, the .ply colour information was in 8 bit format. LAS specifies 16 bit format. So the colours were correct, just meant in the COPC viewer all the points were dark as no 8-16 but conversion is done. Solution was to use laspy and convert the 8 bit colour to 16 bit and then use the converted LAS file and convert that into COPC.